# Помогите с SQL запросом. Нужно правильно отсортировать

Tags: php, sql

Не знаю как правильно сделать запрос SQL. Помогите пожалуйста. Есть запрос такого вида:

```
"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `nick` LIKE ?"
```

при таком запросе выводит все совпадения. Как можно отсортировать правильно и выдать в ответе

1. Выводить с наименьшего к большему по длине строки
2. Вывод начинается с тех букв которые ввели в поиск

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ, который уже был написан ранее должен работать, но как по мне, лучше использовать не `length`, а `CHAR_LENGTH`.

Так мы отсортировали данные по количеству символов, что бы вывод начинался с тех букв, которые ввёл пользователь - просто будем делать поиск именно с тех букв, которые он ввёл:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE `nick` LIKE '$search%'
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(`nick`)
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то так

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM `user` 
WHERE `nick` LIKE '%$search%'
ORDER BY length(`nick`), instr(`nick`,  '$search')
```